# Build:Generic type 'Promise<T, R>' requires 2 type argument(s)

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, compiler-errors, promise

When running my project on Visual Studio I get this error. Is annoying. I cannot even compile

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I would guess somewhere you are trying to create a `Promise<T>` with only a single type argument, but as you haven't posted any of your code there is no way to tell.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a clash between the Promise definition in the NS modules and the ES6 typings. 
As mentioned in answer to similar question [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/generic-type-'promise-t-r-'-requires-2-type-argument), try building against `tns-core-modules.es6.d.ts` instead of the usual `tns-core-modules.d.ts`.